# SQL - Hide repeated values - sql script

Tags: sql

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, s.pid, s.firstname
FROM 
policy p JOIN ips ip ON ip.id = p.id
JOIN sequence s ON s.id = ip.courseid
WHERE
p.id = 9

id     name            pid       firstname
-------------------------------------------
9      PoilicyA         2       SeqA
9      PoilicyA         2       SeqB
9      PoilicyA         2       SeqC
9      PoilicyA         2       SeqD
```

I want to hide the repeated values for the first three columns id, name, pid. Could this would be possible in SQL.

Output:

```
id     name            pid      firstname
------------------------------------------
9      PoilicyA         2       SeqA
                                SeqB
                                SeqC
                                SeqD
```

Comment: Just to reiterate Gordon's point below, this is the sort of functionality that tools like SSRS or Crystal Reports or Tableau or PowerBI are great at. SQL is for retrieving the data. Reporting tools are for presenting it.

Comment: Can you refer a link that could be done in php

Answer (score 0):

This type of transformation should normally be done in the presentation layer.  Why?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  The data one three of the rows depends on ordering, so it is quite brittle.

But, you can do:

```
select (case when seqnum = 1 then id end) as id,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then name end) as name,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then pname end) as pname,
       firstname
from (select p.id, p.name, s.pid, s.firstname,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by firstname) as seqnum
      from policy p join
           ips ip 
           on ip.id = p.id join
           sequence s 
           on s.id = ip.courseid
      where p.id = 9
     ) p
order by id, seqnum;
```

Note the outer `order by`.  This is very important for ensuring that the first row in the group actually has the values.

Comment: I couldn't find the table names in the query. Could you make it with table names