# Combine Multiple Rows into One Cell Using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, qsqlquery

[image]

Hello guys, maybe this is a basic SQL question. How can I combine multiple rows into one cell using SQL?

Expected Result:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SQL doesn't have cells (leastways, not cells that can be merged as in Excel) so not really a valid question. Usually this kind of thing is best handled client-side in your reports where you manipulate the presentation of the data. It is probably possible with some advanced sql to mimic this kind of output - typically its the kind of things "managers" want because it's not good for data work.

Comment: You cannot do this in a Datasheet View but you can in a report: [Hide duplicates selectively](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-21.html).

Comment: Hiding duplicates in query is possible but not simple. Build a report. In any case, the value will not be vertically centered as shown in your example. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320149/how-do-you-suppress-or-hide-duplicate-values-in-sql and http://allenbrowne.com/casu-21.html.

Comment: If you are working within Access, why did you select tag for qsqlquery?

Comment: Ignore the stackoverflow question referenced in previous comment. Doesn't do what I thought. Review this one instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341880/sql-hide-repeated-values-sql-script. It shows approach using ROW_NUMBER function. Unfortunately, Access does not have this function and emulating it is possible but again, not simple (it is a common topic). So, this can be done in Access SQL but not finding example (seen in the past) and not building. You should do research and make attempt if you really, really want this.

Comment: Excel does have cells, and Excel can do this merging of column cells.

Comment: You can also use [Subdatasheets](https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/performance/subdatasheet/index.htm).

Comment: I have the first table in the database, but I am showing it in Excel to illustrate what I want to do.

Comment: Well, then this would actually be an Excel problem and not an Access problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in a query output, but you most certainly can do this in a report.

So, say this simple query of some City and Hotels:

[image]

However, a datasheet output is not suitable for formatted output, and thus you can (should) use a report, and that will allow you to group say the city together, and hide repeating values.

So, a report then can output the above like this:

[image]

And note that you can place a report (as sub form) into an existing form, so even if you not "reporting" the data but only for display, then once again, a report will allow such grouping.

As a general rule, data output to a datasheet view is not formatted, and such output is quite much only for developers. However, for your "users" of the application, then formatting such query output can and should be done with a report.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CONCAT function to add strings together using SQL, identify the names of the columns you want to merge together and write a query with this syntax: CONCAT(no, " ", add) you can us AS function to return the string in a new column you can define the name you want after

Comment: Access does not have intrinsic CONCAT function.

Comment: And would not produce expected output if it did.